# Alert If Data Has not Been Loaded Into PostgreSQL Table

Tags: postgresql, monitoring

Is there any way to alert me if a table or field/column has not inserted any data for that day?

I have a few jobs that insert the data automatically into my tables, but have no way of knowing if it actually ran without me having to query the table.

Comment: Are you using Postgres in conjunction with an application language like Java or C#?

Comment: You could use a time based trigger and a custom function. You mention you have some jobs inserting data - why not log the return of the query so you don't need to look into the db to asure yourself that the data actually was inserted? Or turn on and use the internal log?

Comment: Thank you. do you mean to log the jobs query i have scheduled to insert data?

Comment: I would have a separate table where I track the time of the last relevant data modification. This can easily be done with a statement level trigger.

Comment: I mean the sql return - i.E. if you do an insert you would get `INSERT oid count` in return in case of successful execution..

Answer (score 2):

> ..but have no way of knowing if it actually ran without me having to query the table.

You could have a look into postgresql's internal log:

```
ALTER DATABASE your_database_name
SET log_statement = 'all';
```

Or dive a little bit deeper into it and edit your postgresql.conf like:

```
log_directory = 'pg_log'
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'
log_statement = 'all'
logging_collector = on
```

and restart postgresql

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Or you could have your jobs/services catch the return of the sql-query and have them log it to file if that better suits your need.

Just keep in mind that logs can become quite large over time (depending on the query-frequency)..

**EDIT**

As Laurenz stated in his comment it's better to use

```
 SET log_statement = 'mod';
```

in case it's a 'busy' db. Thanks @Laurenz

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am aware of that - hence my last sentence - but thank you for your comment - I'll add that to my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample how such a thing could be implemented with triggers:

First, the table where we want to check for data modifications:

```
CREATE TABLE collected_values (
   ...
);
```

Now a table where we record data modifications (the `fillfactor` is so that we get HOT updates and avoid table bloat even if there is a high change rate):

```
CREATE TABLE last_updated (
   updated_table regclass PRIMARY KEY,
   mod_time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
) WITH (fillfactor = 40);

INSERT INTO last_updated
   VALUES ('collected_values'::regclass, '-infinity');
```

The trigger function and trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION record_mod() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   UPDATE last_updated
   SET mod_time = current_timestamp
   WHERE updated_table = TG_RELID;

   RETURN NULL;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER record_mod AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON collected_values
   FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE record_mod();
```

Now `last_updated` will always contain the time when the table was last modified. Monitor the values to get an alert.

Comment: thank you Laurenz able. I think there is an issue  with the "create trigger" at the end. im getting error "SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT"
  Position: 24"

Comment: Thanks laurenz i got it to work. The trigger was missing a name after "Create Trigger". IS there a way to set up alerts if the table does not get updated? Like by email?

Comment: Sorry, fixed. There is nothing *inside the database* that can alert you; you need some kind of monitoring software.